# how to get differences between two object of same type

Tags: java

is there any library that compare two objects(also  nested object) and return list of same and difference attributes  as result.

like compare object of type Sample(int  id, string  name, String  fname, Object       subObject);

```
Sample obj1= new Sample(1,"name1","john", new Adds());
Sample obj2= new Sample(1,"name2", null, new Adds());
```

and return result like

```
match :    id  -1
mismatch : name  - name1  name2
           fname - john   null
```

also can compare Adds object

Comment: just implement the logic in your class, why the need for a library?

Comment: Note that this is going to necessarily use reflection, which may be inefficient.

Comment: There is furthermore the problems of cycles. If two objects reference each other, you would have to detect this and abort.